# MySQL spatial - within X km range

Tags: mysql, sql, gis, spatial, mysql-5.6

How can I effectively select all cities (points) within a radius of X km of a given coordinates (point) and order them by distance from MySQL table?

I'm using MySQL 5.6 with the following table structure (imported from Open Street Maps):

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
 `OGR_FID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SHAPE` geometry NOT NULL,
 `osm_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `code` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fclass` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `population` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `OGR_FID` (`OGR_FID`),
 SPATIAL KEY `SHAPE` (`SHAPE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This table stores the coordinates of the cities as POINTS in the `SHAPE` column (`geometry` type). The number of cities is quite a large number (at least for the whole country).

I was thinking extracting the point coordinates from SHAPE column to separate latitude and longitude columns, then using [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), to calculate distance, but this wouldn't be much effective.
Maybe a simple query to limit the cities to an envelope (square region of a similar size) first?

How would you approach this?
What would be the final SQL?